# Fixed Point and Contraction Mapping

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Consider $Tf(x) = \int_0^x e^{-f(s)^2} \; ds$ for $x \in [0,\infty)$. I want to use the contraction mapping theorem to show that $T:C^1([0,\infty)) \to C^1([0,\infty))$ has a unique fixed point.

From the Mean Value Theorem, $\frac{|e^{-x^2}-e^{-y^2}|}{|x-y|} = |-2c e^{-c^2}| \le \sqrt{2/e} < 1$ for some $c$ between $x$ and $y$.

I attempt to replicate this with functions: $\frac{|e^{-f(s)^2}-e^{-g(s)^2}|}{|f(s)-g(s)|} = |-2c_s e^{-c_s^2}| \le \sqrt{2/e}$, where $c_s$ is between $f(s)$ and $g(s)$ and varies with $s$. (Is this OK? I am fairly certain MVT is used, but I don't know if this "generalization" is correct.)

Then, we have
$$
\|Tf-Tg\|_\infty \le \int_0^x | e^{-f(s)^2} - e^{-g(s)^2}| \; ds
\le
\int_0^x|f(s)-g(s)| \sqrt{2/e}
\le \|f-g\|_\infty \sqrt{2/e} \cdot x
$$

So if $x < \sqrt{e/2}$, then this is indeed a contraction. But I can't make any progress when $x \ge \sqrt{e/2}$... Would it be sufficient to say there is a solution for $T:C^1((0,\sqrt{e/2})) \to C^1((0,\sqrt{e/2}))?$ and since $C^1((0,\infty)) \subset C^1((0,\sqrt{e/2}))$ we're done?

Comment: Once you have a unique solution over $[0,a]$, then extract the value of the solution at $a$ and write a new equation with $f(a)$ added. Use a connectedness argument to extend to $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: So I have a unique solution $h(x)$ on $[0,a]$, and then I want to solve $Tf(x) = h(a) + \int_a^x e^{-f(s)^2} \; ds$ for $x \in [a,\infty)$. But then I still can't get a contraction since $[a,\infty)$ is not finite... can you explain this connectedness part?

Comment: Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the set of $a \ge 0$ for which the equation has a unique solution on $[0,a]$. Show that the set is both open and closed in $[0,\infty)$. Once you have existence and uniqueness on $[0,a]$, then you can extend further by $Tf$ as given in your last comment; that's how you get "open". Closed follows by continuity.

Comment: What is the complete metric space on which $T$ operates?

Comment: @TrialAndError I understand that $\mathscr{C}$ is closed. Open, not so much. But what does the fact that $\mathscr{C}$ is open & closed imply? I am failing to see the bigger picture.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter This is a good point that I glossed over. I know $C^1(K)$ is complete w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ for compact $K$, and I'm fairly sure $(C^1([0,\infty)), \| \cdot \|_\infty)$ is not complete, so I can't use the CMT directly. Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: It is open because, if you can extend to $[0,a]$, then you can extend past $a$ using the modified integral equation with $f(a)$ added. So it then extends uniquely to $[0,a]$ for all $0 \le a < b+\epsilon$. Define $\mathscr{C} = \{ a : \mbox{ unique solution exists on } [0,a] \}$. That set is relatively open and closed in the connected set $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @TrialAndError Ah, the openness now makes sense. And now that $\mathscr C$ is open and closed on connected interval $[0,\infty)$, you say that there must be a $C^1([0,\infty))$ solution. Why is this true? (Thanks for sticking with me through all these questions)

Comment: @user288742 : Because that means it extends to every $[0,a)$, and the solution is unique on that interval. So you have a global solution, and uniqueness follows.

Comment: @TrialAndError That makes sense. One final question: Why does the modified integral equation $Tf(x) = h(a) + \int_a^x e^{-f(s)^2} \; ds$ from my 1st comment necessarily have a solution?

Comment: When you look at $Tf-Tg$, the $h(a)$ drops out. $(Tf)(a)=h(a)$ always holds, too.

Comment: So I could advance to $\|Tf - Tg\|_\infty \le \| f - g \|_\infty \int_a^x \sqrt{2/e}$ similarly to the original post, but I'm not guaranteed this is a contraction for all $x$?